# google play core api not returning update available in-app update

Tags: android, google-play-core

I am trying to force app update using in-app updates whenever an update is available in the Play store. However, sometimes even though an update is available in the playstore, when I look for an update programmatically using google play core api I get UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Here is the code snippet:

```
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
        && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
    ) {
        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(appUpdateInfo,
                                                  AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                                                  activity,
                                                  reqCode)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should already have the app with the in-app update code installed from the play store on your device if you want to get in-app updates and it should have a lower versionCode than the update.

If you're testing it using internal app sharing, open the internal-app sharing link in the play store, don't update from there. Now open the app, it will show the update. Make sure the versionCode of the update is higher than the one already installed on your phone.

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#troubleshoot